# How to disable a ribbon button in Excel if a particular worksheet exists with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building an Excel add-in which allows users to interact with PowerPoint and export data. The users have an option to *insert a template* into an existing workbook via a button in the ribbon. When they click this, the button becomes disabled as you can't have two templates in one workbook.

The user may then save their workbook and come back to it at a later point. My issue is that I need to detect that they have the template inserted into an existing workbook and I do this by trying to detect if a named range exists (called `LoadedToken`).

The issue I have is that both the `onLoad` function of the Ribbon and the VBA class `Auto_Open` launch before a large workbook is fully loaded. Therefore I'm not actually detecting if the template exists and can't actually disable the button.

Is there such a thing as events in Excel which can be called at a worksheet level (like `worksheet_open`) but detected in a class?

My code is:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' When the Ribbon loads
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Sub OnRibbonLoad(ribbonUI As IRibbonUI)

    Set MyRibbonUI = ribbonUI
    Dim Authenticate As New AuthenticationClass

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Enable/Disable buttons based on authentication status
    If Authenticate.Authentify = False Then
        Authenticated = False
        Debug.Print ("Unauthorized!")
    Else
        Authenticated = True
        Debug.Print ("Authorized!")
    End If

    ' If the template doesn't exist then disable a grouping on the ribbon
    If TemplateExists = False Then
        Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Grouping1")
    Else
        Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Grouping2")
    End If

End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Check if the Template sheet is visible and prevent other buttons from working
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function TemplateExists()

    Dim Helpers As New HelpersClass

    If Helpers.IsNamedRange("LoadedToken") Then
        TemplateExists = True
    Else
        TemplateExists = False
    End If

End Function


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' From the Helpers Class - Check if a named range exists
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsNamedRange(RName As String) As Boolean

    Dim N As name

    IsNamedRange = False

    For Each N In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If N.name = RName Then
            IsNamedRange = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Note: The authentication class is just another class to connect to my API.

Comment: @findwindow there's no need as this is a discursive question

Comment: @findwindow good feedback. I've addressed the final sentence.

Comment: Well, not the fanciest, but you could add an `Application.OnTime (Now+Timevalue("00:00:02"))` to the Auto_Open to delay the check. This doesn't feel right though, and may be unstable.

Comment: Oh, maybe you can try grabbing events with a `WithEvents` from a class.

Comment: @vacip I've added some code to allow us to formulate an answer. Vacip could you demonstrate the WithEvents feature? My code should be detailed enough.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know it exists and can be used for this, but I myself have never used it. :( If you do come up with a solution, please post it as an answer, I'm curious.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx